# How to get column names of a table in influxdb

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I am trying to work with a database that I barly know and I need to know  column names of a table:

Here is what I tried:

```py
client = DataFrameClient(host, 8086, username, password, "marketdata")
client.switch_database('marketdata')
print(client.query("show measurements"))
# ResultSet({'('measurements', None)': [{'name': 'bookTicker'}]})

query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT bookTicker) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'marketdata'"

dataframes = client.query(query)
```

```sh
raise InfluxDBClientError(self.error)
influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: retention policy not found: information_schema
```

I also tried:

```py
query = "select * from bookTicker limit 10"
```

```sh
raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use `SQL` knowledge for nonSQL InfluxDB.

`InfluxDB` doesn't have concept of columns, but tags (in SQL meaning something like indexed column) and fields (something like a column).

You can explore them with the queries:

> SHOW TAG KEYS [ON <database_name>] [FROM_clause] [WHERE <tag_key>  ['<tag_value>' | <regular_expression>]] [LIMIT_clause] [OFFSET_clause]

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/schema_exploration/#show-tag-keys

> SHOW FIELD KEYS [ON <database_name>] [FROM <measurement_name>]

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/schema_exploration/#show-field-keys